# How can I create a workflow that validates json on a different branch

Tags: node.js, git, github, workflow

I would like to create a PR workflow that makes sure's a users addition to a JSON list in a Javascript file is valid. I was thinking I could run some nodejs code to validate it in a way I see fit. How would I set up a PR that can access a file from a different branch? The .github folder is on the root branch and I'd like my workflow to be their.

Comment: Files in Git aren't "on branches": they're in *commits* (which are then on branches, but the distinction here is important). The way to make GitHub do things with the CI is to use the GitHub CI stuff, which has nothing to do with Git proper, it's just that you have to store the .yml files in commits.

Comment: What you'll need is for the commit that is to be tested (that was just made) to contain the right directives for the GitHub CI. The .yml file can then list various commands to run; these can include Git commands that extract particular files from particular commits, but in general if you can use some existing GitHub action to do everything, that makes your work much easier. Whether there are existing GItHub actions for this, I have no idea.